# Множественное дублирование навигации в slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, slick.js

Использую на странице несколько slick каруселей (слайдеров) у этого плагина есть замечательное свойство appendArrows/Dots которое позволяет создавать контейнер и запихивать туда всю навигацию для удобства ее позиционирования. Но так как на странице используется несколько одинаковых каруселей и они все инициализируются одним классом то в каждой карусели появляется вся навигация со всех каруселей на странице и получается [вот такая вот каша](http://prntscr.com/hu4j49). Я догадываюсь как можно решить эту проблему, в документации описано что в свойство appendArrows/Dots можно вставить нужный jquery селектор, но я не пойму какой.

Вот пример кода инициализации на всякий.

```
$(".sm_slider").slick({
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    appendArrows: '.sl_nav',
    appendDots: '.sl_nav'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Инициализируйте слайдеры из набора в цикле, обращаясь к конкретным экземплярам - this

```
$('.sm_slider').each(function (idx, item) {
    var carouselId = "carousel" + idx;
    this.id = carouselId;
    $(this).slick({
        appendArrows: "#" + carouselId + " .sl_nav",
        appendDots  : "#" + carouselId + " .sl_nav"
    });
});
```

[> оригинальный пример, используемый для ответа <](http://jsfiddle.net/81t4pkfa/2/)